# Android 10 Gesture Navigation Clipping Drawer

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have encountered and issue with the new (Android 10+) gesture navigation, where navigation drawer is being "clipped" at the bottom of the screen:[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMcO5.png).
Important detail to note is that it only breaks "sometimes".

The rest of the activity content is being drawn properly (the blue color in the screenshot is a mapbox map, panning around map just fine).

After some debugging I came to following conclusions:

- it is occuring only with gesture navigation - using either of the "old" 2/3-button navigation with transparency, or using opaque navigation-bar on works fine ,
- it is **not** caused by any inset, padding, nor margin ([verified with layout inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KXXE.png)),
- it is happening only with the fragment containing map (mapbox); when showing any of the other fragments (using standard android views), it it always fine,
- it is sometimes showing properly even on the mapbox fragment, but it can break at any time (noticed it breaking even when no layout changes were occuring).

Does anybody have any idea what causes it, or rather how to fix it?
At this point I am speculating if it is some weird rendering issue caused by the mapbox.

Thank you guys in advance.